# Understanding a Python function

Tags: python, function

I need some help understanding a function that i want to use but I'm not entirely sure what some parts of it do. I understand that the function is creating dictionaries from reads out of a Fasta-file. From what I understand this is supposed to generate pre- and suffix dictionaries for ultimately extending contigs (overlapping dna-sequences).
The code:

```
def makeSuffixDict(reads, lenSuffix = 20, verbose = True):
    lenKeys = len(reads[0]) - lenSuffix
    dict = {}
    multipleKeys = []
    i = 1
    for read in reads:
        if read[0:lenKeys] in dict:
            multipleKeys.append(read[0:lenKeys])
        else:
            dict[read[0:lenKeys]] = read[lenKeys:]
        if verbose:
            print("\rChecking suffix", i, "of", len(reads), end = "", flush = True)
            i += 1
    for key in set(multipleKeys):
        del(dict[key])
    if verbose:
        print("\nCreated", len(dict), "suffixes with length", lenSuffix, \
            "from", len(reads), "Reads. (", len(reads) - len(dict), \
            "unambigous)")
    return(dict)
```

Additional Information: `reads = readFasta("smallReads.fna", verbose = True)`

This is how the function is called:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    reads = readFasta("smallReads.fna", verbose = True)
    suffixDicts = makeSuffixDicts(reads, 10)
```

The smallReads.fna file contains strings of bases (Dna):

> "> read 1
>
> TTATGAATATTACGCAATGGACGTCCAAGGTACAGCGTATTTGTACGCTA
>
> "> read 2
>
> AACTGCTATCTTTCTTGTCCACTCGAAAATCCATAACGTAGCCCATAACG
>
> "> read 3
>
> TCAGTTATCCTATATACTGGATCCCGACTTTAATCGGCGTCGGAATTACT

Here are the parts I don't understand:

```
lenKeys = len(reads[0]) - lenSuffix
```

What does the value [0] mean? From what I understand "len" returns the number of elements in a list. 
Why is "reads" automatically a list? edit: It seems a Fasta-file can be declared as a List. Can anybody confirm that?

```
if read[0:lenKeys] in dict:
```

Does this mean "from 0 to 'lenKeys'"? Still confused about the value.
In another function there is a similar line: `if read[-lenKeys:] in dict:`
What does the "-" do?

```
def makeSuffixDict(reads, lenSuffix = 20, verbose = True):
```

Here I don't understand the parameters: How can `reads` be a parameter? What is `lenSuffix = 20` in the context of this function other than a value subtracted from `len(reads[0])`? 
What is verbose? I have read about a "verbose-mode" ignoring whitespaces but i have never seen it used as a parameter and later as a variable.

Comment: It seems clear that this `makeSuffixDict` function expects that `reads` is in fact a list (if you don't pass it a list, it won't work). Do you have documentation for this function that specifies its requirements?

Comment: Lots of questions in here and I'll answer a few: the brackets are slice notation, so `read[:lenKeys]` means "everything in `read` up to index number `lenKeys`". Similarly, `read[-lenKeys]` is just an index, but using a negative operator. So, "`lenKeys` objects back from the end of `read`".

Comment: There is no documentation, Greg. This was available with the smallReads.fna file for a programming course i guess. I'll edit the content of the fna-file which i just read can be declared a list. It contains strings of bases (dna).    @a p: thanks, that clarifies that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tone of your question makes me feel like you're confusing things like program features (`len`, functions, etc) with things that were defined by the original programmer (the type of `reads`, `verbose`, etc).

```
def some_function(these, are, arbitrary, parameters):
    pass
```

This function defines a bunch of parameters. They don't *mean* anything at all, other than the value I give to them implicitly. For example if I do:

```
def reverse_string(s):
    pass
```

`s` is probably a string, right? In your example we have:

```
def makeSuffixDict(reads, lenSuffix = 20, verbose = True):
    lenKeys = len(reads[0]) - lenSuffix
    ...
```

From these two lines we can infer a few things:

- the function will **probably** return a dictionary (from its name)
- `lenSuffix` is an `int`, and `verbose` is a `bool` (from their default parameters)
- `reads` can be indexed (string? list? tuple?)
- the items inside `reads` have length (string? list? tuple?)

Since Python is dynamically typed, this is *ALL WE CAN KNOW* about the function so far. The rest would be explained by its documentation or the way it's called.

That said: let me cover all your questions in order:

1. What does the value [0] mean?

> `some_object[0]` is grabbing the first item in a container. `[1,2,3][0] == 1`, `"Hello, World!"[0] == "H"`. This is called indexing, and is governed by the `__getitem__` magic method

2. From what I understand "len" returns the number of elements in a list.

> `len` is a built-in function that returns the length of an object. It is governed by the `__len__` magic method. `len('abc') == 3`, also `len([1, 2, 3]) == 3`. Note that `len(['abc']) == 1`, since it is measuring the length of the list, not the string inside it.

3. Why is "reads" automatically a list?

> `reads` is a parameter. It is whatever the calling scope passes to it. It does appear that it *expects* a list, but that's not a hard and fast rule!

4. (various questions about slicing)

> Slicing is doing `some_container[start_idx : end_idx [ : step_size]]`. It does pretty much what you'd expect: `"0123456"[0:3] == "012"`. Slice indexes are considered to be zero-indexed and lay *between* the elements, so `[0:1]` is identical to `[0]`, *except* that slices return lists, not individual objects (so `'abc'[0] == 'a'` but `'abc'[0:1] == ['a']`). If you omit either start or end index, it is treated as the beginning or end of the string respectively. I won't go into step size here.
>
> Negative indexes count from the back, so `'0123456'[-3:] == '456'. Note that` [-0]`is not the last value,`[-1]`is. This is contrasted with`[0]` being the first value.

5. How can reads be a parameter?

> Because the function is defined as `makeSuffixDict(reads, ...)`. That's what a parameter ***is***.

6. What is lenSuffix = 20 in the context of this function

> Looks like it's the length of the expected suffix!

7. What is `verbose`?

> `verbose` has no meaning on its own. It's just another parameter. Looks like the author included the `verbose` flag so you could get output while the function ran. Notice all the `if verbose` blocks seem to *do* nothing, just provide feedback to the user.

Comment: From your edit: note that the `reads` in `reads = readFasta("smallReads.fna", verbose = True)` is in your module scope, while the `reads` inside `makeSuffixDict` is in the function scope. They're *different!* Though I would hazard a guess that `makeSuffixDict` is called with that same `reads` variable.

Comment: thanks! this explains a lot. I'm new to Python so it's true that i confuse many things. I edited how the function is called into the question.

Comment: From what I understand this is supposed to generate pre- and suffix dictionaries for ultimately extending contigs (overlapping dna-sequences). Just added that to the initial post.

Comment: @grindbert yeah I don't know *anything* about the subject. To me it looks like `reads` is a list of strings, and each string is supposed to be the same length so `lenKeys` is calculated only once so `read[:lenKeys]` is everything before the suffix and `read[lenSuffix:]` is the suffix.